# Same secret for different services in k8s

Tags: kubernetes, openshift, kubernetes-secrets

I have a situation when I want to use one Opaque secret in different service
the only difference is that **key** should have different name:

f.e.

**service1** should have env.variable named **TOKEN** and value **SUperPassword111!**

**service2** should have env.variable named **SRV__TOKEN** and same value **SUperPassword111!**

Is it possible to use following secret for those those two service?

Here is the YAML for the secret

```
kind: Secret
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: some_secret
immutable: false
data:
  TOKEN: U1VwZXJQYXNzd29yZDExMSEK
type: Opaque
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The name of an environment variable is specified within the container-spec while the value is referenced with `secretKeyRef` which specifies the secret to use and the `key` within this particular secret.

In other words, the name of the environment variable and the key as used in a secret are entirely independent. So, if I understood your question correctly, the answer to it is; yes it is possible.

See https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/secret/ for a detailed explanation and a full example for referencing a secret from a pod.

Here a simple excerpt tailored to your question:

container-spec for `"service1"`

```
...
  containers:
  - name: service1
    image: service1-image
    env:
      - name: TOKEN # the name of the env within your container
        valueFrom:
          secretKeyRef:
            name: some_secret
            key: TOKEN # the name as specified in the secret
...
```

container-spec for `"service2"`

```
...
  containers:
  - name: service1
    image: service1-image
    env:
      - name: SRV__TOKEN # the name of the env within your container
        valueFrom:
          secretKeyRef:
            name: some_secret
            key: TOKEN # the name as specified in the secret
...
```

Comment: Thank you for you answers. This was exactly what I tried to achieve. Just tried this in my environment and it worked! And thanks for pointing me to the documentation - will review it again, since I looked at this page just before posted my question.